# OptaPlanner - No beans of SolverManager and SolverManager types found in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, optaplanner

I've added `optaplanner-spring-boot-starter` dependency on a **Spring Boot** application but injected `SolverManager` and `ScoreManager` beans were not found on **Intellij**.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method myBusinessBeanAPI in 
mypackage.MyRestResource required a bean 
of type 'org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager' in your 
configuration.
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Injecting the SolverManager/ScoreManager should just work. What do you mean with *in IntelliJ*? Where did you get this logging? How can we reproduce it?

Comment: As I told to AbhinabaChakraborty, The Optaplanner depedency was transitive and I added it to the pom of the module were the solver is injected and it works. Thank you !

Comment: For my information, would you mind specificying the exact `artifactId` of the dependency that you needed to add? Normally, only `optaplanner-spring-boot-starter` should do the trick (no need to add `optaplanner-core`).

Comment: Yes that's what I did. Thanks

Comment: And do I have to inject SolverManager and ScoreManager in unit tests ? Or can I instantiate it without xml ?

Comment: You can inject SolverManager and ScoreManager in your unit tests. We're working also allowing ScoreVerifier to be injected, which is very useful for testing constraints.

Comment: In my unit tests, I don't have any annotation that permit me to use @Autowired. I want simply  instantiate SolverManager and ScoreManager without xml. Because this maven module is the Domain  (DDD) and I don't have any of Spring dependency for tests. I have only OptaPlanner dependency in my domain.

Comment: Take a look at `CloudBalancingConstraintProviderTest`. Those unit tests can test constraints, without running the solver. The ones that do run the solver, should inject the SolverManager, in my opinion, otherwise your tests might diverge from what you put into production. That being said, it's possible to do it they way you suggested too, with the create() methods.

Comment: Thank you @Geoffrey De Smet

Comment: I didn't find this class : CloudBalancingConstraintProviderTest. Where is it ? in the examples in Github ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#solverManager), it says In Quarkus and Spring Boot, the SolverManager instance is automatically injected in your code. Otherwise, build a SolverManager instance with the create(…​) method:

```
SolverConfig solverConfig = SolverConfig.createFromXmlResource(".../cloudBalancingSolverConfig.xml");
SolverManager<CloudBalance, UUID> solverManager = SolverManager.create(solverConfig, new SolverManagerConfig());
```

So probably you didnt import the dependency correctly.
If you are using maven and using dependency management config:

```
<dependencies>
...
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
            <artifactId>optaplanner-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
...
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
                <artifactId>optaplanner-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>7.38.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

If you are using gradle:

```
compile 'org.optaplanner:optaplanner-spring-boot-starter:7.38.0.Final'
```

Comment: I've already added this dependency with the same version, but I haven't used `create` method yet. I'll try and tell you. Thanks. But I would have liked not to use xml for the configuration

Comment: Sorry but optplanner was a transitive dependency. I added it to the pom of the module were the solver is injected and it works. Thank you.

Comment: You shoudn't have to call `SolverManager.create()` on Spring Boot (in fact, if you do it like above, your classloader isn't set properly). The `@Autowired` of a `SolverManager` should just work if you've added `optaplanner-spring-boot-starter` to your pom.xml.